# jquery-steps styling finish button

Tags: jquery-steps

I'm trying to style the Finish button for jquery-steps, however it appears to have an inline style:

`<li class="ui button" aria-hidden="false" style="display: list-item;">`

How can I remove this style, it's interfering with my styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in css like

```
li.button { display:block;}
```